# How to append a column and related columns under another column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

The code to reproduce data is

```
 data = {
    'datetime': ['2019-01-01 08:03:00', '2019-01-01 08:04:00', '2019-01-01 08:04:00'],
    'own_mmsi': [236385000, 236385000, 244013009],
    'target_mmsi': [244013009, 244013009, 236385000],
    'own_lat': [59.330711, 59.330400, 59.327970],
    'own_lon': [10.515833, 10.514336, 10.515833],
    'target_lat': [59.327478, 59.327970, 59.330400],
    'target_lon': [10.515475, 10.515833, 10.514336],
    
}
```

I wanted to get the target_mmsi, target_lat and target_lon and and the same datetime as a row for entire df.

This is the desired first 2 rows of the output.

| datetime | own_mmsi | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 08:03:00 | 236385000 | 59.330711 | 10.515833 |
| 2019-01-01 08:03:00 | 244013009 | 59.327478 | 10.515475 |
|  |  |  |  |

I tried to merge the df with logics but merge does no work wihtin the same df.

```
melted_df = pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=['datetime', 'own_mmsi', 'CRI'],
    value_vars=['target_mmsi', 'target_lat', 'target_lon'],
    var_name='attribute',
    value_name='value'
)

# Pivot the melted DataFrame to reshape it
reshaped_df = melted_df.pivot_table(
    index=['datetime', 'own_mmsi', 'CRI'],
    columns='attribute',
    values='value',
    aggfunc='first'
).reset_index()

# Rename columns for clarity
reshaped_df.columns.name = None  # Remove the name of the columns index
reshaped_df = reshaped_df.rename(columns={'target_mmsi': 'own_target_mmsi', 'target_lat': 'own_target_lat', 'target_lon': 'own_target_lon'})

print(reshaped_df)
```

Comment: "*I tried to merge the df with logics but it seems not working.*" -> how? please provide your exact code

Comment: IIUC: `df.merge(pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={'own_lat': 'lat', 'own_lon': 'lon'}), how='left')`

Comment: Or `df.rename(columns={'lat': 'own_lat', 'lon': 'own_lon'}).merge(pd.DataFrame(data), how='left')` depending on the desired names in the output

Comment: @mozway Both gives the same result of the original dataframe 'data'

Comment: You said you have two dataframes, let's call them `df1` and `df2`. Please provide a [mre] for `df1` and for `df2` and the matching expected merged output.

Comment: I have mentioned the code to reproduce data. That is the only df I have .

Comment: Then what is the expected output? And what is `CRI`, there is no such column in your example.

Comment: I removed CRI for ease of the code. The CRI is not important as of now. The expected output is the table which I have shown in the questions. The target_mmsi and own_mmsi shares a common date time. I wanted to get the target_mmi, target_lat, target_lon as rows with the same datetime as it had. The expected output would have columns datetime, mmsi, lat, lon.